# How can I get the list of ldap users without being sudo?

Tags: linux, ssh, users, ldap

I have non-sudo ssh access to a server of which I want to know the list of users, I think the server is using ldap because:

```
-bash-4.2$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd: files ldap
group: files ldap
shadow: files ldap

hosts: files dns
networks: files

protocols: db files
services: db files
ethers: db files
rpc: db files

netgroup: nis
```

but:

```
-bash-4.2$ cd /etc/sssd/
-bash: cd: /etc/sssd/: No such file or directory
```

Please note neither of `/etc/passwd`, `ls -lsa /var`or `getent passwd` is giving the list I want (they don't even include my own username)

So, does anyone have any idea on how I can get the list of usernames and ids of this server?

```
-bash-4.2$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy)
Release:    7.11
Codename:   wheezy
```

Comment: Does `getent passwd {0..65535}` work for you? See also [How can I list all user names and/or home directories?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/409407)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it certainly does help a lot and gives a much better result than what I had already tried but it still doesn't include my own name but it includes some names from the users that had been created probably 18 years ago in the system:))! I didn't actually know this system is from that long ago:)) Would you be so kind to explain to me what that command does!? what does getent passwd 5 do for example? I mean know the seq thing;)

Comment: I vote to repoen, on my suse 12.1 getent passwd will list entry from /etc/passwd, not Active directory on which can be listed by `wbinfo -u`

Comment: @Archemar did you try getent passwd {0..65535}?

Comment: @Archemar maybe your system is using ids larger than 65535 for example my system was using 88113657 for my id

Comment: If `getent passwd` doesn't show your own user, try `getent passwd $(whoami)`.  If that works, then your LDAP is not being enumerated (a very unfriendly configuration).  You might be able to fix that in, e.g. `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` by setting `enumerate = true`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably the ldap configuration doesn't allow enumeration.

If you know the range of user ids, you could try and get a user list by querying every possible user id:

```
getent passwd {0..65535}
```

Here assuming a shell with support for the `{x..y}` form of brace expansion (zsh, bash, ksh93, tcsh, yash -o braceexpand).

Note that on Linux, uids are  no longer limited to 16 bits, and some Microsoft AD or samba based directory servers at least often use values greater than 65535. Querying `{0..2147483647}` would be out of the question though.

Your network admins are probably not going to like that, as it means doing a lot of LDAP queries to the directory server.

Note that since the *primary key* in the `passwd` database is the user *name*, not id, there may be more than one id for each user name, an `getent passwd <id>` returns only *one* entry, so you may be missing some users.

If users are generally in at least one group beside their primary group, one way to get a list of users could be to query a list of groups with the same methods and look at their members:

```
getent group {0..65535} | cut -d: -f4 | tr , '\n' | sort -u
```

Here `sss` is not used. You'd have `sss` instead of `ldap` in the `nsswitch.conf`.

That would be `libnss-ldap` (or possibly libnss-ldapd, check with `dpkg -l | grep ldap`) handling queries for `ldap`. Configuration is possibly in `/etc/libnss-ldap.conf` or `/etc/ldap.conf` or `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`.

If you  can read those, then you'd find out the server name and details of where the users are in the directory tree, and you may be able to use `ldapsearch` to get the relevant information (provided you're granted access).

Comment: Is it possible to get the userids within a gid?! because I have most of the gids. Also I'd like to know if it is possible to get all the gids.

Comment: Again, `getent group {0..65535}` might help (and provide you with a way to find out more user names).

Comment: won't ldap/active directory users and group comme with id far above 65535 ? (I know active directory is not mentionned here, but I never seen ldap not being active directory, if OP is ldap only this should be fine)

Comment: @Archemar, I've never come across MSAD, but I can confirm a samba equivalent of MSAD having uids above 65535, so I've changed the text.

Comment: There is probably a reason why the ldap doesn't support enumeration, it could be bad for performance if 1000+ machines enumerate 5000+ users all the time. This probably means it is also very bad to enumereate them like this in a script.